# "Possible dupe" popup won't go away

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

I keep getting the following popup on a question I asked recently:

[image]

I've already edited my question to clarify why it's not a dupe of the suggested question. I've also selected the "No" option and clicked "Submit" several times, yet it keeps coming back.

**Is this a bug or intended behavior? If it is intended, what's the purpose of it never going away?**

Comment: I haven't dug into this too deeply, but the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/226118/timeline) shows 2 close reviews completed as "Leave Open" and the post shows 2 close votes, so maybe the people trying to close it keep trying again and again?

Comment: @DavidW It displays whenever I refresh the page, so unless they have a bot auto-flagging this question, I don't think that's the case. Unless their original flag is overwriting the updates somehow.

Comment: Main meta report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342500/398063

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks for that. I've added my statement.

Comment: @mods, It's [status-review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342500/282094).

Comment: @Rob That's the same link Jenayah posted

Comment: DCOPTimDowd, correct. A week later it's been decided upon. When the moderators happen upon your question they can add the red tag, neither of us can make the edit.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug with this component where it only worked part of the time. It should now work in all cases. I have also added functionality to it to delete the "is this a duplicate" comment that is associated with the rejected flag(s).